# Strange behaviour in a C code under gcc 4.4.3

Tags: c

I came across this piece of code today while tutoring some students in a C programming language course.
The exercise asked to implement two functions. The first one scans input from a user and the second displays what has been previously scanned.
The code I came across is the following:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myInput(int i,int n)
{
  int cpt;
  int tab[n];   

  for ( cpt=0; cpt<n; cpt++)
  {
    printf("Enter a number :");
    scanf("%d",&i); 
    tab[cpt]=i;
   }
 }



void myDisp (int n)
{
  int tab[n];      
  int cpt;

  for ( cpt=0; cpt <n; cpt++)
  {
    printf("%d ", tab[cpt]); 
  } 
}

int main()
{
  int n; int i;
  printf(" Entrer the numbers of elements you want: \n");
  scanf("%d \n",&n);
  int tab[n];
  myInput(i,n);         
  myDisp(n);
}
```

---

Although this code is full of inconsistencies, it does actually work under gcc 4.4.3: it displays the numbers that have been input!!!!!!
Does anyone understands how come these code works?

Thanks very much

Comment: For future reference: please highlight your code and press Ctrl+K or click on the button with '0 1' and such to format your code. Thanks.

Comment: This is perfectly valid C99, from what I can see.

Comment: @Electro, @birryree: He probably is looking at the use of the uninitialized variable `tab` in `myDisp`.

Comment: -1 for "Why does incorrect code give a result that looks like what I wanted it to do?" C does not guarantee that incorrect code gives wrong results, and only weakly guarantees that correct code gives correct results... ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If that works, it's through sheer dumb luck.  What is printed in `myDisp` is uninitialized stack, which may or may not contain the data that was put into similarly named variables in `myInput`. [Related reading](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html)

Here's an easy way to break it with do-nothing code:

```
void myInput(int i,int n)
{
  // Add some variables to mess up the stack positioning.
  int breaker;
  int cpt;
  int stomper;
  int tab[n];
  int smasher;

  for ( cpt=0; cpt<n; cpt++)
  {
    printf("Enter a number :");
    scanf("%d",&i); 
    tab[cpt]=i;
   }

  // Trick the compiler into thinking these variables do something.
  breaker = 1;
  smasher = 3 * breaker;
  stomper = smasher + breaker;
  breaker = stomper * smasher;
 }
```

Another way to break it would be to put a function call (say, to `printf`) between the calls to `myInput` and `myDisp`.

Comment: To expand: You may be getting lucky that `myDisp` is allocating `tab` in the same segment of memory as in the other functions. It appears to work, but the code is not correct, and needs fixing.

Comment: Hi Nathon! I've just recompiled under gcc and run it. It works. It displays the numbres I've input!!!

Comment: @strangeLoop: Sure, but try compiling with -O3.  Does it still work? Does it display all the numbers you input in the correct order?

Comment: Hi Thanatos! Since the memory is not freed at the end of myDisp, it should be lost. So the pointer in myDisp should not point to this memory location!! Am I wrong?

Comment: @strangeLoop: The memory isn't lost, it's just left on the stack. When you get a new stack frame for `myDisp`, it uses the same (un-cleared) memory.

Comment: @Nathon: but the data should be lying on the heap! I mean tab[i] are located on the heap. Am I wrong?

Comment: @strangeLoop: You are definitely wrong. If it had been `malloc`ed, it would be on the heap. Variables declared in functions like that are called automatic or stack variables and live on the stack.

Comment: @Nathon: Ah ok, now i see why it works and why your example does actually break it!! I was confused with this dynamic array without explicit dynamic allocation. The data goes to the stack. Since the two functions have the same stack and there is no code in between the two calls, it gives the same numbers. OK, thanks very much Nathon! thanks for the link as well!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work, at least not consistently.  Granted I have gcc 4.4.4 not 4.4.3

```
$ ./a.out
 Entrer the numbers of elements you want:
5
2
Enter a number :Enter a number :4
Enter a number :1
Enter a number :2
Enter a number :3
2 4 1 134514562 3
```

Moral of the story is when you access uninitialized memory, anything can happen, including the *appearance* of working.

Answer (score 0):

Since the two arrays are completely separate it really should not work. If it does it's just because they ended up in the same location in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it works because the memory location of the `tab` local to `myInput` e `myDisp` happens to be (almost?) the same.

It doesn't sound so weird to me: `myInput` and `myDisp` have almost the same signature (they differ for just one `int` parameter); even in the worst case scenario the locations on the stack referred by `tab` in the two functions would be still correctly aligned and shifted at most by two `int`*s* (`i` and `cpt` in `myInput`).

Answer (score 0):

It appears the program is accessing the same memory location for every array `int tab[n]` you declared but, as mentioned, it should not work.

But I think what's happening here is something like: you are allocating tab[] inside main(), let's say, under the address 0x00000001 (take it as an example only). The array have n integers but no values at all.

Then you go into myInput(), declare the array again (same size), in other address, like 0x001F0000, and then set the values, one by one.

So, when the function terminates, it frees the allocated memory of its variables, so your array does not exist anymore.

But wait, this is C, so when you free the memory, you only tells the heap (or the memory allocator, in general) that the addresses can be used again. You do NOT exactly remove the values from memory.

Then you call myDisp() and declare your array again. It appears the memory you just requested has higher priority and then it is somewhat given again to your program. So your array is again instanciated and on the same address.

So, even if you did not fill it with values, the memory is read (as it is always valid in C) and the values are still there.

Oh, and the array declared inside main()? Nothing happens to that. Try to print its values and I bet you'll not have the correct ones.

That is my guess.

EDIT: Just to see things happening: try to declare another array after tab (do not rename tab), say tab2, same length, and use it to put your values instead of tab, then let the program run again :)

Comment: Yes, well the array in the main() scope is completely useless. I just rewrote the code as I was given. Should this array declaration be commented of, the code still runs and gives the good values!

Comment: Sure. I'm blamming the memory heap for this situation. In my opinion, as I stated, You declare that array and the heap gives you one address X because it was on top of the heap. Then you free X and it will top the heap again (sounds odd), and then the heap will give you the same address when you declare tab again.